# Align pandas dataframes with multiindex

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I have two pandas dataframes `df1` and `df2` with a different multiindex. I would like to align both dataframes according to the last index level. The shorter dataframe rules, i.e. all the dates that are not in the shorter dataframe should be removed from the longer dataframe.

If I were to drop the first two index levels, I get the result I am looking for. However, I would like to preserve the complete multiindex.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

idx1_l1 = np.tile("provider_1", 31)
idx2_l1 = np.tile("provider_2", 22)
idx1_l2 = np.tile("indicator_1", 31)
idx2_l2 = np.tile("indicator_2", 22)
idx1_l3 = pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01", end="2020-01-31")
idx2_l3 = pd.date_range(start="2020-01-10", end="2020-01-31")
data1 = np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=31)
data2 = np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=22)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1, index=[idx1_l1, idx1_l2, idx1_l3])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2, index=[idx2_l1, idx2_l2, idx2_l3])

df1, df2 = df1.droplevel([0, 1]).align(df2.droplevel([0, 1]), join="inner", axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the new index for the desired level (2 in your case) by [`intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) and then select the rows with [`get_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_indexer.html):

```
idx = df1.index.get_level_values(2).intersection(df2.index.get_level_values(2))
df1 = df1.iloc[df1.index.get_level_values(2).get_indexer(idx)]
df2 = df2.iloc[df2.index.get_level_values(2).get_indexer(idx)]
```

Comment: I like the idea to get the intersection of both indexes. You could further simplify the code by replacing `get_indexer` (never heard of it before) with `reindex`. `df1 = df1.reindex(index=idx, level=-1)` and `df2 = df2.reindex(index=idx, level=-1)`

Comment: @Andi: Thanks for the comment, this is indeed much simpler. Sometimes you don't see the obvious :)

Comment: What would be a pythonic way if I were to use more than two dataframes?

Comment: make an intersection of `idx` and `df3.index.get_level_values(2)` and so on, possibly in a loop?

Comment: Yes, a loop will definitely work, however, I am wondering if this is regarded as "pythonic"? ;-)

Comment: *Large* loops, especially over arrays, are not "pythonic", but in this case I think it's OK. I don't know of any other solution here.